# Weekend vs weekends

Tags: phrases

Where I live in southern California I often hear weekend referred to as plural eg "on the weekends". Is this proper English and is it commonly heard elsewhere or is it just ignorance unique to my region of San Diego? Furthermore where you live do most people use the British English of "at the weekend" or the American English of "on the weekend"?

Comment: When they pluralize it are they referring to one or multiple?  I do laundry on weekends.  We are going to the fair on the weekends?

Comment: Jim is right. We need some example of full sentences, with all necessary context.

Comment: It was singular for [Neil Young's *Out On The Weekend*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyruylD0BWQ) back in 1972. Plural is usually only used with no article, as (Ame?) *I work on weekends* or (BrE?) *He works weekends*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m usually free on *the weekends* I’m home.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question there are two possible ways of talking about a plurality of weekends.

"We will get the job finished by working weekends, for the rest of the year", and "We will get the job finished by working at the weekend, for the rest of the year" are saying exactly the same thing. Both are idiomatic. Another way would be "...by weekend working, for the rest of the year".

As regards "at" or "on" - in Britain we do NOT do things "on the weekend". We do things "on Saturdays" and "on Sundays" but never "on the weekend". We do them "at the weekend".

Comment: In my neck of the woods we can also just say *I work weekends* (not normally including either ***on*** or ***at***), as per *He works nights*. Does that not work in your area?

Comment: To me, @fumblefingers, that has a slightly different meaning, particularly your second example. I would understand a specific shift, or at least work that needs done at a specific time, not just extra work to get the work done. If you work shifts you could work mornings, afternoons, earlies, lates, nights, weekends etc. Maybe you use it more widely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But if the boss says he needs it by Monday morning, you might say "It's ok, I'll do it at the weekend". (Or you could say "I'll do it over the weekend.) An American would in all likelihood say "Ok, I'll do it on the weekend". "I work weekends" is used in a different context - I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ignorance. It may be a local variant but that makes it interesting, not wrong. Of course there is limit to how unusual your speech can be. One element is when other people start complaining, which you can put down to their prejudice. But the other is when they can't understand you. This structure is immediately and clearly understandable so it is fine in my view, even if it sounds a wee bit strange to me.